# Setting a default value of control in Grocery CRUD + Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, crud, grocery-crud

I need to set a default value of the field in Grocery CRUD.

Basically, the respective data column `IsActive` is set to `NOT NULL`.

I need to see that while adding the record, `IsActive` should be set to `true` or `false` but not `NULL` by default.

I looked for a reference all over the Internet but did not got the perfect solution for that.

Current view (in add mode)

[image]

So in case I do not set the `rules` to `required`, the form will post a `NULL` to the database.

While I need something like this (by default).
[image]

So that the user is not required to add a value (it is not mandatory to set the field to true of false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set default rules for a column at the database level irrespective of any framework/library. Use DEFAULT keyword.

```
   IsActive ENUM('active','inactive') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'active'
```

Comment: thanks buddy, that's a cool idea. I really did not thought that way. I just had to set the default value of the column in my database and CRUD will be generated automatically

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to add code for this, in the database you have to add default value: 0 for inactive, 1 for active, like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `name_of_the_table` CHANGE `IsActive` `IsActive` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '1';  //this will make active be set as default


ALTER TABLE `name_of_the_table` CHANGE `IsActive` `IsActive` TINYINT(1) NULL DEFAULT '0';  //this will make inactive be set as default
```